# Disable videos in YouTube, listen to the audio only

Tags: youtube, video, audio

My internet connection is quite slow (128 kbps while browsing) and I want to know if I can disable video streaming on YouTube and listen only to the audio portion.

There are many songs on YouTube that I want to listen to with no need to watch the video. Will the streaming rate increase?

Comment: I do not believe the audio and video are on different files at youtube so streaming then separately or ony 1 of them seems very hard.

Comment: yes that is the whole point...... any workarounds

Comment: Well aside downloading them instead of streaming them i don't think there is.

Comment: SO there is no way of using less bandwidth and still listen to those beautiful songs...

Comment: Well ehm i would know 1 thing but that's not something i would do myself but you could check it out Opera(webbrowser) has a function they call Turbo(http://www.opera.com/browser/turbo/) it compresses files before sending them over which would reduce the amount of mb's you will have to download. On normal webpages it works slower because it has to encrypt it and decrypt it before you can use it. Other then that i cannot help you any further.

Comment: If you want to listen to YouTube videos on your phone (Android only) you can use the following app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zeem it downloads MP3 locally

Comment: It is now possible to download the audio and video parts of a youtube video separately, directly from youtube.  The command-line tool `youtube-dl` can do this.  Use the -F option to list available formats, and the -f option to select an audio-only format (e.g. 140 or 141).  I'm not aware of any webapp which assists with this, or any way to get the youtube site to play audio-only.

Comment: `youtube-dl` still downloads whole video, extracting audio part is post processing option. My option is to find/create dedicated server with better internet connection which would extract audio part. And make web-browser extension to implement this functionality in youtube.

Comment: @Minimihi, no, that is not correct. We can download the AAC audio part separately using youtube-dl, and even play it while it's downloading. I have done this dozens of times.  For most HD videos, the command to download the best audio stream is `youtube-dl -f 141 $URL`.  I would post this as an answer, but I can't do that because certain other muffin-heads posted bad answers so the question is locked down a bit.  I'll go seek some reputation and come back later!

Comment: @Sam Watkins, yeah... seems you're right. I skipped --format option since in docs it was in video format options block.

Comment: any1 who is interested in youtube-dl here is project link https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/

Comment: One possible partial solution is to set the video quality to the lowest possible setting.

Comment: I just joined this community, so I cannot answer, but http://www.youtube-mp3.org/ is extremely lightweight and pretty fast aswell (It claims to take about 3-4 minutes per video, but for 10 minute video's I've never found it to take over 20 seconds. Besides, I've found that the cache is huge (I recently re-downloaded a small video (<1K views) after months, and the file was still in cache)

Comment: what operating system? I have tried to give a cross-platform answer

Comment: Since at least 2016, in the paid version of YouTube (now called YouTube Premium, formerly called YouTube Red) there is an option called "Use audio mode", see https://support.google.com/youtubemusic/answer/6313574

Comment: You can use the extension Music Mode for Youtube (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/music-mode-for-youtube/abbpaepbpakcpipajigmlpnhlnbennna) that blocks the video playing only the audio. It will save your bandwidth and your CPU usage.

Answer (score 16):

There's an **extension for Chrome**, called "**Audio Only Youtube**" that does just that:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/audio-only-youtube/pkocpiliahoaohbolmkelakpiphnllog

[image: Audio only youtube enabled]]
(NB: this also allows you to scrobble the tracks to Last.fm, eg: with this extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lastfm-scrobbler/hhinaapppaileiechjoiifaancjggfjm )

Comment: There is a same extension for Firefox: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/youtube-audio/.

Comment: does this Chrome extension actually block from downloading the video, or does it just hide the video from the user? The whole point of streaming audio is to disable video to save bandwidth/data. Asking because I read the extension reviews.

Comment: I discovered this Firefox extension just now, and was asking myself the same question. I guess one could check by watching the quantity of data downloaded with / without the extension activated and check... but I'm lazy and won't try.

Answer (score 8):

There are a lot of solutions in **Linux**, under [this U&L question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/229787/32012). See details there, where also some solutions mentioned are **cross-platform**.

The general idea is that a YouTube track can be played as audio-only if:

- it is played in a video player with some 'no video' argument
  or
- only the audio stream is sent to an external player

To send the YouTube track stream to the player the simplest way is probably **SMTube** - more [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/229812/32012).

Open SMTube, search your title, right click on it, and select **Open audio with**:

[image]

Another cross-platform solution is to use Firefox with some add-ons: FlashGot or OpenWith.

See **[here](https://superuser.com/a/819188/162573) how to use Firefox with FlashGot add-on or with OpenWith add-on in order to start YouTube (and other) videos in external players.**

In FlashGot options the arguments can be added like here:

[image: FlashGot Options]

In OpenWith addon options, select Edit>Arguments,  like here:

[image: OpenWith settings]

**FlashGot** add-on for Firefox can also **select just the audio stream** of the YouTube video as seen under the link above.

Selections look like so, after right-clicking the FlashGot icon that appears when playing the YouTube video in Firefox, and selecting 'Available formats'

[image: FlashGot available formats]

then 'DASH (separate audio and video tracks)'
[image: after selecting 'DASH']

In this case, audio-only players can be used - some work and some don't (as far as I can tell testing in Linux, [Audacious](http://audacious-media-player.org/) works). I will update this after testing more.

One of the best players to be used in this way is [`mpv`](https://mpv.io/) as video player. 
The command `mpv --no-video` will start it without video, but also without any GUI or window: to enable window/GUI in all cases, add `profile=pseudo-gui` in its config file, as indicated [here](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/issues/1808); in Linux it's `~/.mpv/config`, for Windows look [here](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/issues/458), or, just use another argument:

Example for Linux:

`mpv --no-video --profile=pseudo-gui`

To start VLC without video the commands are :

```
cvlc --vout none <URL>
cvlc --no-video <URL>
```

But from my experience `mpv` works better that VLC for this purpose.

Answer (score 6):

Try http://navarr.me/ytaudio/

You usually need to check the "Allow YouTube to collect cookies" option for it to work.
I've been using it with my slow DSL service and for things you want to hear and don't care about video, it works great.

Comment: looks interesting. are you sure it is only streaming audio part of video, even in background?

Comment: Works great! Yes cookies have to allowed for it to work.

Comment: I think you're misinformed, this simply generates an embeded YouTube player, if you set the video to none it simply hides the playback. See the render code for the app here: https://github.com/navarr/ytaudio/blob/master/src/AudioPlayer.php#L842

Comment: ..or see the description: "YTAudio does not extract the audio from YouTube videos, nor does it eliminate the overhead of processing YouTube videos when playing the files."

Answer (score 2):

If it is a song, you can replace `www` with `music` and it loads the audio stream. Then you have to click the "Song | Video" toggle to turn off the video.

[image: Screenshot of YouTube music interface to select song or video]

Example:

Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MYPsPCC-K7c

Audio only: https://music.youtube.com/watch?v=MYPsPCC-K7c

But it does not work yet in all cases. It must be music.