# How can I preserve my bandwidth by getting only the audio?

Tags: youtube, video, audio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable videos in YouTube, listen to the audio only](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/15603/disable-videos-in-youtube-listen-to-the-audio-only)

I use YouTube as a radio, listening to a different playlist every time.  I don't watch, I just listen.

If audio only is not possible, can I at least specify a very small screen size?

I guess small phones use an API that I could use as well.

The:

> I have a slow connection. Never play higher-quality video.

setting is not enough.

Comment: This can be done with `youtube-dl`.  For most videos, the command to download the best audio stream is `youtube-dl -f 141 $URL`.