# last.fm with less YouTube video bandwidth?

Tags: youtube, video-streaming, last.fm, bandwidth

For audio while working I like last.fm:

- it's great for ambient, jazz, world, and instrumental/non-vocal generally
- it runs well on linux and in firefox (both of which I use)
- it's free in the US

However they recently switched to a YouTube-based player, which combines video and audio, increasing the service's bandwidth. Can the video bandwidth be reduced, ideally to zero? Some things I've tried that don't work completely:

1. [FlashBlock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flashblock/). With the old last.fm player I could FlashBlock the video portion of the player, but the new player will play neither audio nor video unless I whitelist youtube.com, in which case I get both the video and audio.
2. YouTube player settings--i.e., the gear icon. This allows one to set video quality (e.g., 144p, 360p), so I tried just setting to the lowest quality/bandwidth=144p. This works for awhile, but seems to regularly reset itself to higher quality.
3. [YouTube account settings](https://www.youtube.com/account_playback). I had hoped one could set the default video quality to, e.g., 144p. However, the best one can do is set "Never play higher-quality video" which seems to allow any setting below HD.

Answer (score 1):

No it cannot be reduced without affecting the content.

A service like FetchMP3 creates an MP3 version of the audio in the YouTube video. Other services which can do this include Listen To YouTube and Save YouTube

See [Disable videos in YouTube, listen to the audio only](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/15603/disable-videos-in-youtube-listen-to-the-audio-only)